# How to adjust rules priority of Windows Firewall?

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

In Windows 10, I have created a "Block All" outbound firewall rule. I created another rule to allow Chrome and put it above previous rule. But still, Chrome isn't getting connected. How to give Chrome rule higher priority than "Block All" rule?

The objective is: I want only Chrome to use my Internet connection (background processes are using it fully and I am unable to do real work on Chrome). Please, don't suggest to use Net Balancer etc. I want to achieve my goal using Windows Firewall without touching existing rules (so that I could get back to exist setting easily after my work is done). Is it possible?

Comment: Add Chrome as an exception in Firewall settings,
under Outbound rules, new rule, with rule type as program, provide path to exe, allow the connection, apply all profiles and finally, name the exception rule (chromeout or something..)

Comment: the MS firewall is not set up as a packet filter cascade rule-set, so there isn't any logic surrounding the order of rules. you allow what you want to allow, and block what you want to block, but that does mean that you cannot block all with exceptions as you would in a standard cascade filter. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-configure-windows-7-firewall

Comment: @Frank What's the solution then?

Comment: you need to set the firewall to block all outbound connections by enabling the setting "Outbound connections that do not match a rule are blocked". Then you can create your exception rule. The only issue with this is that you will have to periodically confirm that the new apps and updates you install do not add an allow rule automatically. you will have to remove any undesired allow rules. http://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/